# Undefined subroutine &abc::abcUtil::PERL_DEBUG

Tags: perl

I have a perl module : `abcUtil.pm` which has a subroutine check :

```
package abc::abcUtil
require "common.pl"
sub check {
   ..
   PERL_DEBUG("");
   // PERL_DEBUG is in common.pl
   ..
}
```

When I execute this , it works fine, But when i use this pm in another perl:

```
require "common.pl"
use abc::abcUtil
sub func {
    abc::abcUtil::check();
}
```

Here, if I call `func()`, I get this error :

```
"Undefined subroutine &abc::abcUtil::PERL_DEBUG .."
```

There are other direct occurrences of `PERL_DEBUG` in this perl file which are working fine.

What might be wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that if you have two `require` statements for the same file in your program, the file is only brought in once.  So, in this case it is only being brought in to your main file.  Therefore, the module can't see it.

`require` with a file name is not really a sophisticated mechanism for including code.  It is basically a step above `eval`.  If you want to have your own library of common functions that can be used in both places, just make them into a module.  Then you will have no problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem is due to two require statements. If i remove the require statement from the base perl, it works fine. But that was just a test. I need the common.pl in both the files and also since the subroutines that i require are already present in common.pl, i do not want to rewrite it to a module. Is there any other way around this problem ?